# Financial forecasting and Optimal order submission

Tags: high-frequency, forecasting, algorithmic-trading

For instance, If i have a model that can accurately forecast 3s ahead, would the trading logic be rather trivial? I have fit a series of distributions to L2 data and believe I have a fairly good grasp as to what will happen in a few seconds. Now I am at the stage where I have to design some logic in order to get trades into the market. I am working on both passive and aggressive strat, as I have generated signals for both.

Just wanted to know if that if the better the model, then you can get away with having a more basic trading logic.

Comment: Your question isn't well-formed.  Since there is a bid-ask spread, all of us generally know the price of the next trade as it will be public for small orders.  What makes it "optimal"?  Optimality depends entirely on the standard being used and the axioms on which it is built.  An optimal solution under quadratic loss won't be under all-or-nothing loss, generally.  A solution that is Bayesian will not match one that is Frequentist, generally.  Please expand your question so we can know what you are really trying to ask.

Comment: I somewhat intentionally left it unclear, but I will shed some colour on what I am asking. I have constructed a model that is able to accurately forecast a few seconds ahead using L2 data, for which I have fit a series of distributions. I am now in the position of designing the trading logic, and just wanted to know how important the trading logic is conditioned on the fact that we have a 'forecast' of a few seconds with reasonable accuracy.

Comment: You are not considering how the system would change once you placed orders.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience and good signal is only part of the problem you are solving. Good software engineering, good trading logic, good error handling and good economic reasoning all play important roles as well.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the trivial answer but first of all saying that you have a “good 3s signal” is not even a well defined statement, so i let you reassess your prior on the “triviality” of the monetization :)